# DNS A record pinging to ip but shows error 404

Tags: web

I need to open the content of the ogilvyalbaniaonline.com, at test.whateveryouwant.a2hosted.com
This is done via DNS A record.
If you check the images below, the DNS Configurations are all ok, and if i ping both of the sites, they both show the same IP address. But when i open test.whateveryouwant.a2hosted.com on a browser, it shows 404 error.
what am i doing wrong? advice?

[image: original content]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

404 is an application error.  If you had a DNS issue, you would have not gotten a 404, you would have gotten a connection refused error.

You need to add a index.html to the server root of your filesystem.  Nothing to do with DNS at all.

Comment: *500 errors aren't connection refused; they are server-side errors.

Comment: The browser often reports a 50x error when there's a connection issue.  But you're right - it's dependent on how the browser renders the error.

Comment: Well, if you open ogilvyalbaniaonline.com , it will show the content.
it has the index.php configured as default.

Comment: Yep, and you need to do the same configuration on your test.whateveryouwant.a2hosted.com server